# Misplaced backslashes

Tags: support, status-completed, mathjax, comment

I left a comment at [Strict ordering on natural numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5427/) but as you can see it says "Misplaced \\". I'm no more allowed to edit it myself, I don't know why. Can someone correct it please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed.

Markdown in comments use a different set of rules than Markdown in posts. In particular, `\{` will not be converted to `{` in comments, so `\\{\\emptyset\\}` will be left as-is. It is incorrect to place a `\\` there in LaTeX, thus the error.

Comment: Is there any good reference on the version of markdown in comments vs. posts?  Why the incompatibility?

Comment: @Bill: it seems like comments are parsed with regex in real time, instead of storing the parsed HTML, so [some rules](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64706/italics-markup-not-working-in-comments/64709#64709) [are restricted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51091/what-happened-to-comment-formatting/60172#60172) [to save resource](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49201/comments-inline-links-with-a-parenthesis-not-working-properly/49222#49222). There is no good reference except by experimenting. ( :( )

Comment: Thanks, that useful to know to help understand the design compromises.